# legend in R plot display all lines

Tags: r, plot

I have a following problem.
I want to put a legend into my graph. My code:

```
plot(Lc(`BEL_2016_final.csv`$value),col="red",lwd=2, 
     xaxt="n", yaxt="n", cex.lab = 1.5)
axis(side=1, at=axTicks(1), cex.axis = 1.5)
axis(side=2, at=axTicks(2), cex.axis = 1.5)

par(new=TRUE)

plot(Lc(`CRO_2016_final.csv`$value),col="blue",lwd=2,
     xaxt="n", yaxt="n", cex.lab = 1.5)
axis(side=1, at=axTicks(1), cex.axis = 1.5)
axis(side=2, at=axTicks(2), cex.axis = 1.5)

legend(x = "topleft", legend=paste0(c("Belgium, Gini "),
                            round(Gini(`BEL_2016_final.csv`$value), digits = 2),
                            c("Croatia, Gini "), 
                            round(Gini(`CRO_2016_final.csv`$value), digits = 2)),
       col=c("red", "blue"), lty=1:2, cex=1, lwd=1.5)
```

However, the legend looks like this:

[image]

When I try:

```
legend=paste0(c("Belgium, Gini ", "Croatia, Gini "),
                                    round(c(Gini(`BEL_2016_final.csv`$value)),
                                    Gini(`CRO_2016_final.csv`$value)),
                                   digits = 2)
```

I got this result: [image]

which is wrong, because Gini index for Croatia is 0.73.

How can I modify my code to display both lines (red and blue) in the legend, both on a new line? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try `legend=paste0(c("Belgium, Gini ", "Croatia, Gini "), round(c(\`BEL_2016_final.csv\`$value, \`CRO_2016_final.csv\`$value), digits = 2))`.

Comment: @r2evans do you mean `round(c(Gini(` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, the intent is to show that your `paste0` is combining too much. Really it's just `legend=paste0(c(locations), round(values, digits=2))`, you fill in the patterns.

Comment: @r2evans sorry, but it still did not work properly. See my edit, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct solution is:

```
legend(x = "topleft", legend=paste0(c("Belgium, Gini ", "Croatia, Gini "),
                                    c(round(Gini(`BEL_2016_final.csv`$value), digits = 2),
                                    round(Gini(`CRO_2016_final.csv`$value), digits = 2)
                                    )),
       col=c("red", "blue"), lty=1:2, cex=1, lwd=1.5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your parentheses are mismatched. Whatever IDE/editor you are using I encourage the use of matching (sometimes "rainbow") parentheses. For example, in RStudio, if the cursor is the `_` symbol (and accepting RStudio's insistence on its indentation preference):

[image]

notice that the `(` next to `paste0` is highlighted, suggesting you that `digits=2` is the last argument in `paste0`. *This is incorrect.* Another hint is using RStudio's indentation preference (highlight the block and press `Ctrl-I`, the default keypress for "Reindent Lines"): the second `Gini` lines up with `c(`, not with the first `Gini`, meaning that `c(` and second-`Gini` are at the same level ... where I would expect the second-`Gini` to be nested within the `c(`.

To validate what is going on, I'll replace the `Gini(.)` calls with your `0.52` and `0.73` values, verbatim (but please keep them as `Gini(.)` in your code:

```r
paste0(c("Belgium, Gini ", "Croatia, Gini "),
                                    round(c(0.52),
                                    0.73),
                                   digits = 2)
# [1] "Belgium, Gini 0.52" "Croatia, Gini 0.52"
```

Looking at it this way, it appears as if the first right-paren after `0.52` might have been intended to be after the `0.73`, since grouping 0.52 and 0.73 makes sense.

Here is corrected code, where all I do is remove one right-paren from after the first-`Gini`, and add one right-paren to the very end of this expression:

```r
legend=paste0(c("Belgium, Gini ", "Croatia, Gini "),
              round(c(Gini(`BEL_2016_final.csv`$value),
                      Gini(`CRO_2016_final.csv`$value)),
              digits = 2) )
```

and the associated matching-paren highlighting (again, `_` is the current cursor):

[image: rstudio with corrent paren-matching]

> `<soapbox>`
>
> PS: I am not saying that one *must* use the RStudio IDE for R work. In fact, I don't, I use emacs/ess. There are other editors to use as well. However, as much as indentation and similar can be viewed as *style* and therefore not important for programming, I argue that indentation and some editor functionality like matching-parens can help in readability as well as troubleshooting code before you even get to a mistake; for instance, a consistent indentation style alone here hints to improper paren-closure, and the matching-paren-highlighter confirms it. Use what you prefer, but some programming *styles* are actually beneficial *functionally* (and therefore pragmatic).
>
> `</soapbox>`